# What is the proper procedure of celebrating new year?

Tags: scripture, rituals, festivals, vedic-rituals, celebrations

Yesterday, it was seen how some Hindus were overexcited in celebrating the Christian New Year in a typical European fashion. Yet the same enthusiasm is absent while observing the Hindu New Year, which is mostly limited to  rather non-religious activities like carrying out processions, cleaning houses, eating good food & wearing new clothes. This might be due to ignorance about the related rites, as New Year celebrations aren't mentioned much in religious literature. So what is the proper way to ritualistically observe Hindu New Year ?

Comment: Nice question. Even i was discussing about the same with some of my friends the previous day about the same viz the baisakh nava varsha. ..

Comment: There is no single Hindu new year (different parts in India observe it in different times of the Gregorian cal.). And its celebration depends on family traditions and region. It doesn't have a single coded type of way to celebrate. So, there is no single proper way, instead there are many ways which are considered proper in different parts by different families/clans.

Comment: Also, wearing new clothes, cleaning one's house, making special dishes etc. on special religious occasions  specifically are practices which are part of tradition. However, in one thing I would agree with you that gradually many people are ignorant of their own indigenous new years and have forgot how to celebrate it. Many may not even know that the Hindu new years don't coincide with the Christian new year. And this is extremely sad. Chinese new year is celebrated with so much pomp. However, Hindus and others like Jainas etc, are forgetting and drifting more and more toward western practices.

Comment: I didn’t even know they were different. Don’t I feel like an idiot  I was westernized 100%  After reading this thread, had to google when is Hindu new year 2023, to get the dates. Ok then ! Good to go. Learn something new every day  Thx for making this topic ! 

Comment: Well, that's about true in a sense i guess cz in bengali, assamese, etc the year starts with vaishakh and in odia, maratha, etc its from chaitra. But, none the less monts are almost same. So, people should remember their own cultural new year. Yeah we celebrate it with new cloths, pakwans, pitha, ganesh puja, building straw houses n burning it later at morning, after spending n celebrating a night in it with families n friends, wishing everyone, giving gifts, respecting elders n giving blessings to younger ones, etc etc, but not as huge as the Christian new year. N that's kinda sad.

Comment: Opz, odia also celebrates it in sankranti only. Its gujrat actually but i guess they also celebrate in kartik. Well. Happy New Jesus Year.

Comment: .️️⚡⭕☮️.

Comment: The 'Christian' new year is not christian. Although the current western calendar was started by a Pope (hence its name Gregorian calendar), It was done simply because it was more accurate than the prior calendar (Julian) which was Roman pre-chriistian, and not Christian. It is not a religious festival. It is more of a recent cultural event. For many centuries it was not celebrated.

Comment: Which Hindu new year are you referring to? The lunar or the solar??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Year according to the Hindu lunar calendar, falls on *Caitra śuklā pratipada*.

*[Viṣṇudharmottara Purāṇa](https://archive.org/details/9000000004657SriVishnuDharmottaraMahapuranam1000pSANSKRIT1929/mode/1up)* prescibes the worship *Brahmā* in the morning on that day after keeping a fast on the previous day alongside His *āvaraṇa-devatā*s & other deities of time & donation of gold.

The other deities to be worshipped on the New Year according to the *[Nīlamata Purāṇa](https://archive.org/details/nilamatapurana/mode/1up)* are

1. The 9 *graha*s
2. The 28 *nakṣatra*s
3. The 14 *manu*s
4. The 14 *Indra*s
5. The 4 *yuga*s
6. The 5 *saṁvatsara*s
7. The 2 *ayana*s
8. The 6 seasons
9. The 12 months
10. The 2 *pakṣa*s
11. The 16 *tithi*s
12. The 11 *karaṇa*s
13. The 30 *muhūrta*s
14. The 12 *raśi*s
15. The 4 aims of life
16. The 4 *dikpāla*s
17. The 8 *lokapāla*s accompanied with their wives, children & hordes
18. The daughters of *Dakṣa* alongside their respective husbands.
19. *Kuvera* accompanied with the treasures *Śaṅkha* & *Padma*, his wives *Ṛddhi* & *Siddhi* , son *Nalakuvara* & *yakṣa*s
20. *Garuṛa* accompanied by *Aruṇa*, birds & serpents
21. The 7 *dvīpa*s
22. The 7 oceans
23. The 7 *varṣa*s
24. The 7 underworld realms
25. The 7 *loka*s
26. The 5 *tattva*s
27. The supporters of the Earth (*Kālagnirudra, Ādhāraśakti, Kūrma & Śeṣa*)
28. The mountains
29. The rivers
30. The *tirtha*s
31. The 7 metres
32. *Skanda* accompanied by *Śākha*, *Viśākha* & *Naigameya*
33. *Gaṇeśa* accompanied by *vināyaka*s
34. *Airavata* accompanied by elephants
35. *Suravī* accompanied by cattle
36. *Uccaiḥśravā* accompanied by  horses
37. Fever personified accompanied by other diseases
38. The scriptures personified alongside their promulgators
39. *Sarasvatī* accompanied by the personifications of the *Veda*s, *Upaveda*s & *Vedaṅga*s
40. The *apsarā*s accompanied by the *gandharva*s
41. The *vālakhilya*s
42. The 7 sages
43. Kaśyapa, Agastya & Nārada
44. The 2 *Aśvin*s
45. The 12 *Āditya*s
46. The 8 *vasu*s
47. The 12 *sādhya*s
48. The 12 *Bhārgava*s
49. The 10 *Āṅgirasa*s
50. *Viśvakarmā*

[The list turns out to be roughly synonymous with those who attend *Brahmā*'s court mentioned in the [*Sabhāparva* of *Mahābhārata*](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02011.htm)]

All of them are to be propitiated by *homa* with ghee, raw rice grains, raw barley grains & sesamum followed by feeding of *brāhmaṇa*s & wearing of new clothes.

*Viṣṇudharmottara Purāṇa* also mentions the following *vrata*s to be performed on that day

1. Initiation of *Brāhmipratipatvrata* - This involves the votary worshipping Brahmā on every *śuklā pratipada* day for the entire year, ending on the next *Caitra suklā pratipada* by donation of a cow to a *brāhmaṇa*.
2. Initiation of *Tṛmūrtivrata* - This involves the votary worshipping *Brahmā* on the first day accompanied with *homa* with *kṣīra* (condensed milk), consumption of only curd on that day & donation of a *kṣīra*-filled iron vessel with gold to a *brahmaṇa*, worshipping *Viṣṇu* on the second day accompanied by donation of *tṛlauha* (gold, silver & copper) to a *brāhmaṇa*, worshipping *Rudra* on the third day accompanied by *homa* with ghee, complete abstinence from food & donation of a ghee-filled iron vessel with gold to a *brāhmaṇa* and special bath on the fourth day accompanied by donation of *tṛmadhu* (ghee mixed with honey & sugar) to a *brāhmaṇa* & consumption of the same. This same procedure is to be repeated on every 1st 3 days of the bright half of the fortnight throughout the year.
3. Initiation of *Puruṣapratipatvrata* - This involves the votary worshipping *Viṣṇu*, recitation of *Puruṣasūkta* while immersed in water, performing *tarpaṇa* of *Viṣṇu* 8 times, performing *homa* with ghee, donation of gold to a *brāhmaṇa* & consumption of only milk at night. This is to be repeated in every *pratipada* day in both halves of the fortnight throughout the year.
4. Initiation of *Prakṛtipuruṣavrata* - This involves the votary worshipping *Viṣṇu* in fire & *Lakṣmī* in water accompanied by *homa* with *kṣīra* mixed with ghee & donation of gold & silver to a *brāhmaṇa*. This is to be repeated on every *śuklāpratipada* day throughout the year.

*Nīlamata Purāṇa* describes the following preparatory rites of New Year

1. Leaving food offerings for *piśāca*s in tree-shades, cowsheds, places where 4 roads meet, highways, abandoned houses, riverbanks,  mountain peaks & *śmaśāna*s at the night of *Caitra kṛṣṇā caturdaśī* after worshipping *Nikumbha*, the king of *piśāca*s & keeping awake throughout the night by enjoying music & dance
2. Feeding dogs after performing the regular *pārvaṇa-śrāddha* on *Caitrī amāvasyā*

*Nīlamata Purāṇa* also recommends performance of *grahaśāntiyagña*, *nakṣatraśāntiyagña* & *mahāśāntiyagña* on this day.

Quoting various *Smṛti* texts, *[Nirṇayasindhu](https://archive.org/details/nirnaya-sindhu-hindi/mode/1up)* mentions the following rites to be observed on this day

1. Refraining from applying oil during bath
2. Donating a water-fountain or a water-filled pot to a *brāhmaṇa*.
3. Initiation of *Caitra Navarātri*

New Year according to Hindu solar calendar falls on *Meṣa saṁkrānti*, which is celebrated by Bengali (Pohela Boisakh), Axomiya (Bohag Bihu), Maithili (Jur Shital), Odia (Pana Samkranti), Tamil (Puthandu) & Malayali (Vishu) Hindus. Since most of the Hindu rituals are observed on the basis of the Hindu lunar calendar, celebration of the Hindu solar new year is without much liturgical pomp. Rites specific to *saṁkrānti* days (performing special śrāddha & donating pots filled with eatables to a *brāhmaṇa*) are prescribed for this day.

Gudi Padwa as observed by Marathi Hindus appears to be remnant of the *Śakradhvaja* ceremony. This ceremony was to be performed only by kings & involved hoisting a flag consecrated to *Indra* for maintaining sovereignty.